# Access Big Query from other Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am Managing two GCP projects by Terraform:

Production and Test.

There is an active Workflow running on **Production** which writes data in an Big Query Database. Now I want to create an Instance on **Test** to work with the data.

How can I access the Data in the Production Big Query from Test?

The service account has currently the roles  roles/bigquery.dataEditor, roles/bigquery.jobUser and  roles/bigquery.user but this seems project specific?

Comment: You need to grand that role on the targeted datasets (or projects)

Comment: As @guillaumeblaquiere said, You just need to add the service account to the access list AKA, share the dataset to an account: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#console

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @guillaume and @Stan, You can provide access to your dataset in Production project by giving the appropriate role to your Service Account/User in Test project. Refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#granting_access_to_a_dataset) for detailed process.

Do note that, to be able to query the tables in the dataset you need permission to run a query job in the project, which can be done by assigning roles/bigquery.jobUser role to the service account/user for the project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Service Account your initialization will look something like this:

```
Google::Cloud::Bigquery.new(
  credentials: JSON_KEY_FROM_HOST_PROJECT,
  project_id: THE_REMOTE_PROJECT_ID
)
```

The gotcha is that the JSON_KEY is from the Host Project whereas the PROJECT_ID is from the Remote Project.  Normally one would expect the project_id to be part of the query, not the client connection, especially since JSON_KEY is tied to a specific PROJECT_ID of its own.

The docs don't give good examples.